# Rails: Store (merge) parameter after Devise Sign In

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, merge, strong-parameters

I have a form that should be submitted after Sign In but all the viewers can see and fill the form. So, I save the parameters in a session variable. After Sign In, I store the parameters successfully. The problem is that I want to add the user_id (which is foreign key) and store it beside the other parameters (before Sign In, the user_id is unknown).
Part of my Controller's code:

```
def create
  if current_user.nil?
        session[:trip] = params
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
  else
        @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @trip.save
...
private

def set_trip
  @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
end


def trip_params
  params.require(:trip).permit(:from, :to, :departure_date, :arrival_date, :user_id)
end
```

As I mentioned, this code stores the new form parameters successfully. To add (insert or merge) the `current_user.id`, I tried these different ways separetely:

`@trip = Trip.new(trip_params.merge(user_id: => current_user.id)`

```
@trip = Trip.new(trip_params)
@trip.user_id = current_user.id
```

`@trip = current_user.Trip.new(trip_params)`

`@trip = current_user.trips.new(trip_params)`

I've tested all of these ways but still the user_id have not been saved!! Please, help me to understand the problem and its solution for Rails4.

Comment: Can you post the params that are generated?

Comment: @Pavan Which parameters do you mean? I've edited the question and added params but I think it's not related to the list of parameters.

Comment: Try removing `user_id` from `trip_params` and check.

Comment: I mean the params that are generated in the log when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Pavan Still the same problem!

Comment: Can you post the log that is generated while saving the trip?

Comment: @Pavan do you mean the log which is saved in `/log/development.log` file?

Comment: No! I mean the info that is generated in the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108738/discussion-between-aboozar-rajabi-and-pavan).

Answer (score 1):

It should work.

```
  def create
      if user_signed_in?
            @trip = current_user.trips.new(trip_params)
            respond_to do |format|
              if @trip.save
                format.html { redirect_to @trip, notice: 'Trip was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @trip }
              else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @trip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
            end
      else
            session[:trip] = params
            redirect_to new_user_session_path
      end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time helping me. It seems to be correct, mostly when you try it in the console. But I still had problems with this answer, as it didn't save the user_id. So, I've used another solution which is explained below. Thank you again and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I've added this new method to the **application_controller.rb**:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

# save list if there is a temp_list in the session
if session[:trip].present?

    @trip = current_user.trips.new(session[:trip]["trip"])
    @trip.save
        session[:trip] = nil
    return @trip
else
    #if there is not temp list in the session proceed as normal
    super
end

end
```

I wish it could be useful for the others.